# AngularJS show two dates without showing similar parts twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

How do I nicely display a date range consisting of two dates? The main thing I'm looking for is to not show something twice if it's the same for both dates. I'm thinking something like this:

> Tue, 05 May 2015 19:31-20:31 GMT
>
> Mon, 04 19:31 - Tue, 05 20:31 May 2015

It's okay if there is some overlap, for example:

> Mon May 4th, 19:31 - Tue May 5th, 20:31 2015

The goal is to get something that is nice for users to look at. I don't know where to get started with this - for now I only know how to show both full dates. I haven't been able to find anything in my searching - plenty on how to format individual dates, but nothing to format two dates together.

I'm using AngularJS, but if you know how to do it without Angular, that would be fine.

Comment: Can you edit your post and show what you have done so far?

Comment: @Mikey I don't know where to get started on this. I don't have anything other than showing both full dates.

Comment: I don't believe it has exactly what you are looking for, but you should look at [angular moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment)

Comment: Take a look at filters.

Comment: @Cerad What filters should I look at for handling two dates? Everything I've found so far is only for single dates

Comment: The idea is to write your own.  Just basic java script.

Comment: @Cerad I have to keep internationalization in mind, so it's not just basic javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The tags in your question suggest you want to format a date range in AngularJS. However, this seems a general Javascript question to me, unless you are want so solve things elegantly using Angular filters.

I suggest you to use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) which has a lot of utility functions for formatting and comparing dates. [`moment-range`](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range) also could provide you some handy methods, however I don't see any formatting methods.

```
var date1 = momentjs('2015-05-05 12:15');
var date2 = momentjs('2015-05-10 12:15');
```

These date have overlapping years, months and times. You can detect this with `date1.isSame(date2, 'year')`. Do this with month, date, time, etc.

Then format your range with `date1.format(...) + ' - ' + date2.format(...)`, depending on what date properties are the same.

Wrap all your code in an Angular filter if you want:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('dateRange', function () {
  return function (date1, date2) {
    // date range stuff here
  };
});
```

Use the filter in your template after setting `date1` and `date2` on the `$scope`

```
{{date1 | dateRange:date2}}
```

Comment: My intention in including the AngularJS tag was to show it is an option, not a requirement. I was hoping there might be something that already exists that would do it, but failing that this should work.

Comment: AngularJS only has a `dateFilter` which formats a single date. Afaik there is no filter that formats a date range. The internet is full of examples that filters a list with items by date range, but that is not what you want. My answer should give you enough directions to create your own date range formatting filter. If you managed to make it, don't hesitate to share your filter as a Angular module on Github ;)